# Add vendor prefixes to the css generated by SASS

Tags: npm, sass, autoprefixer

I have SASS installed via NPM (SASS version 1.32.13 compiled with dart2js 2.12.4) and this setup in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "sass-dev": "sass --watch --update --style=expanded _assets/scss:wwwroot/dist/css",
    "sass-prod": "sass --no-source-map --style=compressed _assets/scss:wwwroot/dist/css"
  },
```

I would like my setup to add vendor prefixes to the generated css. How can this be done best? Autoprefixer, I guess, but how?

Comment: You answered your own question: Autoprefixer

Answer (score 0):

PostCSS plugin to parse CSS and add vendor prefixes to CSS rules using values from Can I Use. It is recommended by Google and used in Twitter and Alibaba.

```
npm i autoprefixer
```

Comment: So what is the new command to transform .scss to .css with prefixes? and what is the command for watch?